# Correct way of anonymously subclassing TimerTask keeping a reference to 'this' inside the run method

Tags: java

I subclassed `TimerTask` with an anonymous 'concrete' class, this way:

```
public void setTimedTask() {
    /* Note: 'this' implements an interface called UpdateIndicatorsReceiver */
    final UpdateIndicatorsReceiver receiver = this;
    final TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /* The interface UpdateIndicatorsReceiver has an updateIndicators method */
            receiver.updateIndicators();
        }
    };
    /* Code to actually set the timer.... */
}
```

Please note the oddity of declaring a local `final` field named `receiver` and setting it to `this`. Is there any cleaner way of getting a non changing reference to `this`, in order to use it in the `run` method of the anonymous class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be unnecessary; you should simply be to invoke `updateIndicators()` directly.

i.e.:

```
public void run() {
    updateIndicators();
}
```

without the need for the `receiver` reference.  This compiles for me.

Comment: And for me, too. I should really review inner classes, and anonymous inner classes. I always get a bit confused about it (especially when they come with "static", "final" and whatsoever), they're the only difficult thing about Java, at least to me.

Answer (score 1):

`UpdateIndicatorsReceiver.this.updateIndicators();`

Comment: The compiler tells me "No enclosing instance of the type UpdateIndicatorsReceiver is accessible in scope". **EDIT**: but I can use the actual class of 'this' and it works. Didn't know how to get the 'this' reference for enclosing classes, thanks. I'll accept this answer after eventually reading some alternatives.

Comment: Yea you will probably need to use `ConcreteClass.this.updateIndicators();` :-)

Comment: I accepted the other answer, but I would have accepted yours too if I could. Thanks for your advice, happy coding.